# Recoger valor del properties sin saber la clave

Tags: java, archivo-de-propiedades

necesito saber como recoger de un properties por el valor del *properties*. Es decir tengo lo siguiente en un properties.

```
usuario.UE0153 = PEpe ccx dkgkdflñfg
usuario.UE1222 = Antonio perez jimenez
usuario.UE1525 = Jaime Perez
```

Tengo que recoger todos los usuarios (usuario.xxx) que aparezcan en el properties sin saber los que son. Es decir al no saberlo tengo que recorrer el properties y recoger cada clave de usuarios. para después recoger sus valores.Pero no saco la manera de recoger las claves. Para después ir recorriendo el valor con las claves.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `keySet()`, te retorna un `Set<Object>` con todas las entradas del properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("usuario.UE0153", "a");
props.setProperty("usuario.UE1222", "b");
props.setProperty("usuario.UE1525", "c");

for(Object key : props.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", key, props.getProperty(key.toString()));
}
//salida:
//usuario.UE1525 : c
//usuario.UE1222 : b
//usuario.UE0153 : a
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Me has dado algo de luz pero el problema esta en que desde java tengo que recoger todos los valores "usuarios.xxx" que tengo en diferentes properties con lo que deberé de revisar cada properties. Seria recoger los valores que en la clave tengan "usuario." pero no consigo que sea como un buscador de "usuario" dentro de todo mis properties . O que se pongan todos los usuarios en un properties y recoger todos las claves valor que empiezan por usuario.  Un saludo y seguire buscando , gracias de nuevo por la ayuda .